# Как мне получить объект member, используя ID пользователя?

Tags: discord.py

У меня в базе данных хранится ID пользователя, нужно используя эти данные получить объект member

Answer (score 0):

[guild.get_member(ID:int)](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)

```py
role = ctx.guild.get_member(382754447924693986)
print(role.name, role.id, role.position)
```